# How to Write mysql Query based on my condition

Tags: mysql, select

How to Write mysql Query based on my condition

when user Register datetime to after 10 to 30 mins.user register datetime to after 10 to 30 mins random or between select user query .

if example

`1) user register datetime is 2017-12-22 06:12:30`

`2) user register datetime is 2017-12-22 07:55:45`

`3) user register datetime is 2017-12-21 23:24:30`

current datetime is 2017-12-22 06:25:22

now i need result is  1st example 
please write mysql select query

`select * from user where reg_datetime='2017-12-22 06:25:22'`

help me

Comment: Look into DATE_ADD, DATE_SUB, NOW() and "IS BETWEEN"

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Please show us sample table data and the output you expect.

Comment: i think if you do enough search you can find the solution very easily.

Comment: i searched but not get efficient solution

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

So you want those datetime between 10 and 30 minutes after the registration date, then you can do this:

```
SELECT *
from user
WHERE reg_datetime >= '2017-12-22 06:25:22' + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
  AND reg_datetime <= '2017-12-22 06:25:22' + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

- [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/075a6f/4)

But this won't return any thing as there is no registration dates after 10 to 30  minutes from the sample date `2017-12-22 06:25:22`.

IF you want **before** you can just use `-` instead of +`. And in this case you will get only the user who registered on`2017-12-22 06:12:30`. Which is the only registration date after 10 or 30 minutes from the sample datetime.

Comment: @Santhosh -What is the expected results that you are looking for? which dates should be returned??

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user
WHERE ('2017-12-22 06:25:22' >= reg_datetime + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
and  '2017-12-22 06:41:48' <= reg_datetime + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)`
this my result query